# Itunes Connect can't delete app

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect

I can't delete a App in Itunes Connect, I am the Team Agent and my App has the status `Preparing for Submission`. But there isn't a Delete App button. Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No matter what your account prevelages are, you can't delete an app on `Preparing for Submission` status.

According to the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).

> Apps that have not been approved yet can’t be deleted

So, for now, you need to sitback and wait for the review result. Once you got the result(whatever accepted or rejected) you can delete your app.

Update 2018: You can now delete unused/never submitted apps from [App Store Connect](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/100002355)

Comment: You cant delete an app that is rejected if it hasn't been published yet previously.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can not delete app directly from iTunes until app rejected from apple. First submit the app for review process after that if your app rejected or except by apple then you can remove it from apple store.

Comment: Rejected apps can't be deleted